# Deploy / Add metadata / Mint supply / Transfer - ALL IN ONE TRANSACTION

Tags: spl-token

I saw something on explorer that it deploy, add metadata, mints, and transfer the token in one single transaction. Is that a bug or he just using the instruction?

[Example scenario](https://solscan.io/tx/3Q2xbnLXdTJVk1q5upN7fym5iZFMqo6STBHXkcBTNSrQuzLC4svSXDb7BxS4nNnvTFuf92msu3GtsSScPLR7mSeX)

Comment: A transaction can have multiple instructions, and this transaction contains instructions to setup the mint and metadata all in one. This is totally normal behavior!